# How to apply CSS styles to dynamically created DOM objects in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular

Please could I ask for help with the following?

I am working in Visual Studio Code. I have an Angular project.

My app.component.html is trivial and is as follows:

```
<button #CreateButton style="position:absolute;width:120px;height:20px" (click)="OnCreateButtonClicked($event.target)">Create Button1</button>
```

My app.component.css file is trivial also, and is as follows:

```
button { color: yellow; background-color: #b87dee; }
```

Am using Renderer2 in my app.compoenent.ts:

```
constructor (private renderer: Renderer2)
```

When I run the app I see my styled button:

[image]

Now, if I use that OnCreateButtonClicked event to dynamically create a button like so:

```
CreateButton(szNullabelID = null, nLeft = 0, nTop = 0, nWidth = 120, nHeight = 20) 
{
    let szID = (szNullabelID == null) ? 'Button' + (this.m_buttons.length + 1) : szNullabelID;

    const newButton = this.renderer.createElement('input');
    
    this.renderer.setProperty(newButton, 'type', 'button');
    this.renderer.setProperty(newButton, 'id', szID);
    this.renderer.setProperty(newButton, 'value', szID);
    
    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, newButton);
}
```

The button is not styled:

[image]

How can I get this dynamically created button to follow the css rule?

Comment: You are creating an `input` while targeting css using `button`. You should be using `input[type=button]` which would work

Comment: You should create a `button` element instead of `input` element.

Comment: Thank you both very much. It is working now.

Comment: Feel free to upvote a remark when it helped you out. ...